# SharePoint 2013 - Reverse Lookup

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, column

I am trying to achieve the following in SharePoint 2013. I have two (2) lists a server list and an application list. Each list contains a lookup column which a user can select which applications are hosted on the server in the server list and which servers host which applications in the applications list. This process is becoming difficult to maintain. What I want to do is have only one of lists have a lookup column in which the user manually selects the server or application and have the other list automagically have a reverse lookup column and populate with the server name column or application name column.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is custom coding out of the question?  An event receiver can be used to update the other list.  Here is this blog, though it's for 2010, so not sure if it'll even work for 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer on the other questions in the forum.

I am sure you want the same thing:

[Relational List fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105334/relational-list-fields/105358#105358)

In essence, if your list Books have a lookup for a list Bookshelf, when you go to web part of Bookshelf, you could add a reverse lookup-like web part from tabs in a way similar to below image.

[image: Diagram to add a relational list]

Comment: Although this points to a great answer, I must say this answer points to an answer, which points to two external links! Somebody with a laptop handy needs to fix this. (That somebody could be me 12 hours from now.)