# Relational List fields

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have 2 lists "People" and "Meetings". I can create meeting and add multiple people to meeting using lookup column. Now, I also have a field in People list called "Meeting assigned" where it should be autopopulated with the meetings certain user is assigned with while creating item in meeting list.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking about the reverse lookup. You can get this done using the relational list.

Here is blog, who is doing the same thing as you want.

http://blog.oneboredadmin.com/2012/12/reverse-lookup-in-sharepoint-2010.html

also check this one
http://www.cloud2.co.uk/10-top-tips-for-sharepoint-part-2-2/

In essence, if your list Books have a lookup for a list Bookshelf, when you go to web part of Bookshelf, you could add a reverse lookup-like web part from tabs in a way similar to below image.

[image: Diagram to add a reverse lookup]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is there a way I can store the information in a column because I need to perform some filtering on those fields later. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The cloud2.co.uk link is dead and doesn't seem to be available on archive.org